# slideDown jquery moves content down

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying use jquery for my project. I managed to do slideDown function, but when I press show more button my image thumbnails jump away.

I am adding codepen.

```
http://codepen.io/garstikaitis/pen/OXNXPY
```

Also adding a webpage:

```
hhttp://arsti.net/FinalBop/product.html
```

Thanks in advance, guys

Comment: It works just fine on my end. Tested on Firefox, Chrome & Edge.

Comment: I mean I would like to keep the left side of content to stay in same position because right now when I expand the description, left side of the website jumps down.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "left side", the entire element is going to be affected accordingly. Do you want a sidebar?

Comment: Yes, by saying left side, I mean big image, and 3 small thumbnails underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mind my comment, I misread the post.

This is because you have two  `<div class="row"></div>` one below the other. The show more will push down everything below it, and thus will push down the thumbnail as well as the button.
You gotta use your grid the other way.

For example, keep only one row and use a col-lg-6 for the big image and small images and another col-lg-6 for the text & button.